# Java backend app / server that receives files uploaded in Angular JS or Javascript (e.g. ng-file-upload or angular-file-upload)?

Tags: web-apps, java, angularjs

I have written a backend Java app that runs fine, uses Tomcat server (though any server would work) and also has a Jersey REST API should I need it.

I also have a nice Angular JS, HTML + CSS web UI for the app, wherein a user uploads a .csv file via `ng-file-upload`.

Sadly, I can't figure out how to connect the frontend and backend, in terms of receiving the uploaded file in Java. The author of `ng-file-upload` doesn't provide any documentation on how to do this and I've been unable to find an example, though Java is supported and there's some example Java code in the library's Github repo, though it has no code comments, docs, or context clues as to how the cryptic code should be used.

Thus I am looking for some open source web app that uses Angular JS (or plain old Javascript) to upload files to a Java backend.